# Java TriviaGame method Printing wrong value

Tags: java

I'm creating a trivia game for two players. It asks them 5 questions each, and after each question it displays if the answer was correct or incorrect and if incorrect displays the correct one. The program compiles and runs and displays properly up until it goes to display the correct answer, it always displays 3, no matter what the actual answer is.

Any help would be appreciated!

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Question
{
private ArrayList <String> questions;
private int answerNumber;
private int questionNumber;
private int [] answers = {3,2,4,3,3,4,4,1,3,3};

public Question()
{
}
public String getQuestion(int number)
{
    return createQuestions(number);
}
public String toString ()
{
    return "Question for player+";
}
public String createQuestions(int questionNumber)
{
    ArrayList<String> questions = new ArrayList<>();

    String question1 = "Who's proffesion was a chef?";
    String question2 = "Who had a son named Ben?";
    String question3 = "Who claimed they were on a break?";
    String question4 = "Who's pick up line was \"How you doin\"?";
    String question5 = "What animal is Chandler afraid of?";
    String question6 = "Who married a gay ice dancer?";
    String question7 = "Who did Rachel almost marry?";
    String question8 = "Who had a pet monkey?";
    String question9 = "Where did the show take place?";
    String question10 = "What was the name of the coffee house?";

    questions.add (question1);
    questions.add (question2);
    questions.add (question3);
    questions.add (question4);
    questions.add (question5);
    questions.add (question6);
    questions.add (question7);
    questions.add (question8);
    questions.add (question9);
    questions.add (question10);

    return questions.get(questionNumber);
}
public String getPossibleAnswers(int questionNumber)
{
    ArrayList <String> possibleAnswers = new ArrayList<>();

    String possibleAnswers1 = "1. Ross\n2. Rachel\n3. Monica\n4. Ross and Monica's mom";
    String possibleAnswers2 = "1. Chandler\n2. Ross\n3. Rachel\n4. Phoebe";
    String possibleAnswers3 = "1. Rachel\n2. Monica\n3. Joey\n4. Ross";
    String possibleAnswers4 = "1. Joey\n2. Ross\n3. Chandler\n4. Phoebe";
    String possibleAnswers5 = "1. Cats\n2. Snakes\n3. Dogs\n4. Monkeys";
    String possibleAnswers6 = "1. Phoebe\n2. Rachel\n3. Janice\n4. Monica";
    String possibleAnswers7 = "1. Ross\n2. Chandler\n3. Gunther\n4. Barry";
    String possibleAnswers8 = "1. Chandler\n2. Ross\n3. Joey\n4. Phoebe";
    String possibleAnswers9 = "1. Atlanta\n2. Detroit\n3. New York City\n4. Las Vegas";
    String possibleAnswers10 = "1. Central Coffee\n2. Coffee Central\n3. Central Perk\n4. There was no coffee shop";

    possibleAnswers.add (possibleAnswers1);
    possibleAnswers.add (possibleAnswers2);
    possibleAnswers.add (possibleAnswers3);
    possibleAnswers.add (possibleAnswers4);
    possibleAnswers.add (possibleAnswers5);
    possibleAnswers.add (possibleAnswers6);
    possibleAnswers.add (possibleAnswers7);
    possibleAnswers.add (possibleAnswers8);
    possibleAnswers.add (possibleAnswers9);
    possibleAnswers.add (possibleAnswers10);

    if (questionNumber == 0)
        answerNumber = 0;
    else if (questionNumber == 1)
        answerNumber = 1;
    else if (questionNumber ==2)
        answerNumber = 2;
    else if (questionNumber == 3)
        answerNumber = 3;
    else if (questionNumber == 4)
        answerNumber = 4;
    else if (questionNumber == 5)
        answerNumber = 5;
    else if (questionNumber == 6)
        answerNumber = 6;
    else if (questionNumber == 7)
        answerNumber = 7;
    else if (questionNumber == 8)
        answerNumber = 8;
    else answerNumber = 9;

    return possibleAnswers.get(answerNumber);
}
public int getCorrectAnswer(int questionNumberAsked)
{
    int answer;

    if (questionNumberAsked == 1)
        answer = answers[0];
    else if (questionNumber == 2)
        answer = answers[1];
    else if (questionNumberAsked == 3)
        answer = answers[2];
    else if (questionNumberAsked == 4)
        answer = answers[3];
    else if (questionNumberAsked == 5)
        answer = answers[4];
    else if (questionNumberAsked == 6)
        answer = answers[5];
    else if (questionNumberAsked == 7)
        answer = answers[6];
    else if (questionNumberAsked == 8)
        answer = answers[7];
    else if (questionNumberAsked == 9)
        answer = answers[8];
    else answer = answers[9];

    return answer;
}

public int getRandomQuestionNumber()
{
    Random random = new Random();
    int questionNumber = random.nextInt(answers.length);

    return questionNumber;
}
public int displayQuestion(int playerNum)
{
        int questionNumber = getRandomQuestionNumber();

        // Display the player number.
        System.out.println("Question for player #" + playerNum);
        System.out.println("------------------------");

        // Display the question.
        System.out.println(getQuestion(questionNumber));
        System.out.println(getPossibleAnswers(questionNumber));

        return questionNumber;
}
}

import java.util.Scanner;

public class TriviaGame
{
public static void main (String [] args)
{
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in);
    Question question = new Question ();
    int userAnswer = 0;
    int player1Points = 0;
    int player2Points = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        int questionNumber = question.displayQuestion(1);
        int player1Answer = keyboard.nextInt();

        if (player1Answer == question.getCorrectAnswer(questionNumber))
        {
            System.out.println("That is correct!");
            player1Points ++;
        }
        else System.out.println ("Sorry the correct answer was "+question.getCorrectAnswer(questionNumber));

        int questionNumberPlayer2 = question.displayQuestion(2);
        int player2Answer = keyboard.nextInt();

        if (player2Answer == question.getCorrectAnswer(questionNumberPlayer2))
        {
            System.out.println("That is correct!");
            player2Points ++;
        }
        else System.out.println ("Sorry the correct answer was "+question.getCorrectAnswer(questionNumberPlayer2));

    }

    System.out.println ("Game Over!\n----------------\nPlayer 1 points: "+player1Points+"\nPlayer 2 points "+
    player2Points);

    if (player1Points > player2Points)
        System.out.println ("Player 1 wins!");
    else if (player2Points < player1Points)
        System.out.println ("Player 2 wins!");
    else System.out.println ("It's a tie!");

}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `getCorrectAnswer()` method is not aware at all of what is the random question number being asked ! And in the same method you have last else block which sets as :

`else answer = answers[9];`

Since `int questionNumber` at class level is having its default value 0 and which is not matching to any condition thus answer has always a value of 3, as per your last else block `answers[9]` array.

> To make it work :

Change your getCorrectAnswer() method as , so that it knows what is the questionNumber asked..

```
    public int getCorrectAnswer(int questionNumberAsked) {
    int answer;

    if (questionNumberAsked == 0)
        answer = answers[0];
    else if (questionNumberAsked == 1)
        answer = answers[1];
    else if (questionNumberAsked == 2)
        answer = answers[2];
    else if (questionNumberAsked == 3)
        answer = answers[3];
    else if (questionNumberAsked == 4)
        answer = answers[4];
    else if (questionNumberAsked == 5)
        answer = answers[5];
    else if (questionNumberAsked == 6)
        answer = answers[6];
    else if (questionNumberAsked == 7)
        answer = answers[7];
    else if (questionNumberAsked == 8)
        answer = answers[8];
    else if (questionNumberAsked == 9)
        answer = answers[9];
    else answer = 0;

    return answer;
}
```

and in the same class make `displayQuestion` method return the randomQuestionNumber generated and is being asked as :

```
public int displayQuestion(int playerNum)
{
        int questionNumber = getRandomQuestionNumber();
        // Display the player number.
        System.out.println("Question for player #" + playerNum);
        System.out.println("------------------------");

        // Display the question.
        System.out.println(getQuestion(questionNumber));
        System.out.println(getPossibleAnswers(questionNumber));
        return questionNumber;
}
```

and finally in main method pass that questionNumber as :

```
int questionNumber = question.displayQuestion(1);
        int player1Answer = keyboard.nextInt();

        if (player1Answer == question.getCorrectAnswer(questionNumber))
        {
            System.out.println("That is correct!");
            player1Points ++;
        }
        else System.out.println ("Sorry the correct answer was "+question.getCorrectAnswer(questionNumber));

        int questionNumberForPlayer2 =  question.displayQuestion(2);
        int player2Answer = keyboard.nextInt();

        if (player2Answer == question.getCorrectAnswer(questionNumberForPlayer2))
        {
            System.out.println("That is correct!");
            player2Points ++;
        }
        else System.out.println ("Sorry the correct answer was "+question.getCorrectAnswer(questionNumberForPlayer2));

    }
```

Comment: I've made the changes that you suggested and for the players 1 getCorrectAnswer print out I still get 3 for everyone one and for player 2 I'm getting 4 for each one. Sorry if it's just something silly I'm missing, I'm just a beginner (As you can probably tell)

Comment: You missed updating the second clause of the getCorrectAnswer method, it still has reference to class variable `questionNumber` instead of `else if (questionNumberAsked == 1)`.
I'd suggest you to update your `getCorrectAnswer()` method as in my answer, I have updated.Also, there are lot 3 and 4 in your answers array, so please check , it is working for me. Or please point which is not working exactly.